# Show products name and quantity in a new column on Woocommerce My account Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

In Woocommerce, I would like to add a new column to My account orders list and show  the name and quantity of ordered the products.

I have this code for instance that adds a new column displaying the order name:

```
function sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {
        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

        if ( 'order-status' === $key ) {
            $new_columns['order-ship-to'] = __( 'Ship to', 'textdomain' );
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column' );

function sv_wc_my_orders_ship_to_column( $order ) {
    $formatted_shipping = $order->get_name;

    echo ! empty( $formatted_shipping ) ? $formatted_shipping : '&ndash;';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-ship-to', 'sv_wc_my_orders_ship_to_column' );
```

How can I change it to display the name and quantity of ordered products?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will add a custom column to My account orders list section, displaying the product name and quantity for each order:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'additional_my_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
function additional_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = [];

    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {
        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

        if ( 'order-status' === $key ) {
            $new_columns['order-items'] = __( 'Product | qty', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-items', 'additional_my_account_orders_column_content', 10, 1 );
function additional_my_account_orders_column_content( $order ) {
    $details = array();

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item )
        $details[] = $item->get_name() . '&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;' . $item->get_quantity();

    echo count( $details ) > 0 ? implode( '<br>', $details ) : '&ndash;';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: $new_columns['order-items'] = __( 'Product | qty', 'woocommerce' );
If it is the title of this column, the Chinese is displayed as "商品x數量"

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Greate! How to add short description of product?

Comment: Replace `$details[] = $item->get_name() . '&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;' . $item->get_quantity();` by this 2 code lines: `$product = wc_get_product ($item->get_product_id() );`and then `$details[] = $product->get_short_description();`…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec is it possible to add multiple columns with this code?

Comment: @OlgaBerning Yes of course it is possible. you need to set a custom key for each.