# Add permalink to product title in WooCommerce custom order history

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, permalinks, orders

I am using [Show products name and quantity in a new column on Woocommerce My account Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550835/show-products-name-and-quantity-in-a-new-column-on-woocommerce-my-account-orders/55551700#55551700) answer code to add an additional column to the Woocommerce My Account Order History page that displays the titles of items for the order.

How would I make the code display the title as a hyperlink to the product page of the item ordered rather than just plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make each product title linked to the product, you can use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'additional_my_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
function additional_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = [];

    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {
        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

        if ( 'order-status' === $key ) {
            $new_columns['order-items'] = __( 'Items', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-items', 'additional_my_account_orders_column_content', 10, 1 );
function additional_my_account_orders_column_content( $order ) {
    $details = array();

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item )
        $details[] = '<a href="' . $item->get_product()->get_permalink() . '">' . $item->get_name() . '</a>&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;' . $item->get_quantity();

    echo count( $details ) > 0 ? implode( '<br>', $details ) : '&ndash;';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.